# How to search a string for substrings that can be in any order using regular expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex, json

I'm currently working with a web service that is outputting JSON data in the following format:

```
{"ID":1291,"Name":"Houses of the Holy","Artist":"Led Zeppelin","Year":1973}
```

However, the order isn't consistent from one item to the next. For example:

```
{"ID":2958,"Label":"Reprise Records","Name":"Electric Ladyland","Year":1968}
```

Naturally I can't write a regular expression that depends on the attributes being in a uniform order, since the order varies from one item to the next (although they always start with ID).

I would use preg_split using ',"' as the delimiter, but there will occasionally be a tracklisting, like this:

```
{"ID":9237,"Tracklist":[{"Track1":"Taxman","Track2":"Eleanor Rigby"}]}
```

...which would mess it up.

How can I use a regular expression to search for substrings that may appear in any order, or perhaps not appear at all? Or will I have to run multiple regular expressions on each item the web services returns, one for each possible attribute?

Comment: This sounds like you need a parser. Can't you use the built-in JSON parser?

Comment: Is [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) not available to you?

Comment: I dont't think the regular expression can do what you need. Use a syntax parser in your case may help.

Comment: +1 for my favorite album Houses of the holy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be easy to access every item by using json_decode()

```
$results = json_decode('{"ID":2958,"Label":"Reprise Records","Name":"Electric Ladyland","Year":1968}', true);
print_r($results);
```

Output:
Array
(
    [ID] => 2958
    [Label] => Reprise Records
    [Name] => Electric Ladyland
    [Year] => 1968
)

Comment: lolz.... looks like we reading each other's mind . One suggestion use TRUE with json decode other wise return will be simpleobject and not array

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Glad to see it's much simpler than I thought!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you dont want to use json_decode()

```
$json_string = '{"ID":1291,"Name":"Houses of the Holy","Artist":"Led Zeppelin","Year":1973}';
 $json_array =json_decode($json_string,true);
```

output will be

```
Array
(
[ID] => 1291
[Name] => Houses of the Holy
[Artist] => Led Zeppelin
[Year] => 1973
)
```

You can then manipulate the array in way you want